# AngularJS UI Bootstrap popover outsideclick trigger closes popover when item removed from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using the AngularJS UI Bootstrap popover with outside click trigger and a popover template. It all works as expected, except inside my template I have an ng-repeat with an option to remove one of the items in the repeat. While this all works, as soon as the item is removed, the popover closes - it is as though it thinks I have clicked outside the popover. Here is a plunk to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/vAk3y779eEmLSmIg9kb4?p=preview

JS:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.dynamicPopover = {
    templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
  };


  $scope.checklistitems = [
    {check: false, text: "item 1"},
    {check: false, text: "item 2"},
    {check: false, text: "item 3"}
    ];

  $scope.delete = function (item) {
    var index;
    index = $scope.checklistitems.indexOf(item);

    $scope.checklistitems.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("yo delete: " + item.text)
  }

});
```

html:

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">


    <span>some text to pad</span>

    <button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl"
    type="button" class="btn btn-default"
    popover-placement="bottom"
    popover-trigger="outsideClick"
    >Popover With Template</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
        <div ng-repeat="item in checklistitems">
          {{item.text}}
          <button ng-click="delete(item)">delete</button>
        </div>
    </script>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had the same problem, I just found out it is a problem when the HTML in the popover changes -- so I changed my `ng-if`s to `ng-show`, your solution could be to tag the deleted items and hide them, and make the real 'delete' when the popover closes! see: http://plnkr.co/edit/2NifZtWtUuqh8CCBTALf?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @Betty St, that's that solution I will go with. If you add as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, I just found out it is a problem when the HTML in the popover changes!

I changed my `ng-if`s to `ng-show` and the popover didn't close when clicking on a button.

Your solution could be to tag the deleted items and hide them, and make the real 'delete' when the popover closes!

Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/2NifZtWtUuqh8CCBTALf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GzbsuProeip6czr0aige?p=preview)

Remove `popover-trigger="outsideClick"`, it should work.

Comment: Yes it will work without that, but I actually want the ability for the popover to close when I click outside the popover - i.e. the outside click finctionality