# angular-ui popover vanish, if a button is clicked inside of popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-directive

I have used `popover` with `popover-trigger` = '`outsideclick`' and inside a popover i used a custom directive to render html.

Now when i click a button inside popover the popover vanishes.

I have created a striped down version of the problem here [Link of problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/2EYqfrPr2gq4IEB3oqcQ?p=preview)

*What am i doing wrong ?
Why is popover getting vanish?
How to fix it?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change ng-if to ng-show, it will work.

```
var template =
          '<ul>' +
          '<li data-ng-repeat="node in ' + appModel + '" >' +
          '<button  data-ng-show="node.collapsed" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeHead(node)">- click me</button>' +
          '<button  data-ng-show="!node.collapsed" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeHead(node)">+ click me</button>' +
          '</li>' +
          '</ul>';
```

This issue maybe due to ng-if removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree, still if you want to use with ng-if you can use `$event.stopPropagation();` in your click function so the event is not propagated.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37674704/3279156

Answer (score -1):

Add one more attribute to your button which triggers popover,  trigger="focus"

```
<button popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" trigger="focus" uib-popover-template="'tree.html'" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover</button>
```